# LaunchDarkly feature flags with celery

Tags: python, celery, launchdarkly

I am trying to run an async task with LaunchDarkly feature flags

When I first starting the worker, it takes the last flag value

But if I'm changing the feature flag value while worker is running - it will not update the value, and it will remain the same

When I'm running celery with `-P gevent` the problem seems to be solved, but we are running in context of only single process

Comment: Is the worker a long-running process, or more task-based?

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue @levlaz. I have a task-based celery task and if I change the values on LaunchDarkly, a new task won't get the proper value.

Answer (score 2):

We solved the issue by setting the client locally for each worker:

```
client = None

@worker_process_init.connect
def configure_worker(signal=None, sender=None, **kwargs):
    global client
    client = ldclient.get()
```